# redux observable with axios onProgress

Tags: axios, redux-observable

i am creating an upload function that will show a progress bar to the client inside a [React](https://reactjs.org/) [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) and [Redux-observable](https://redux-observable.js.org/), and i use [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to do a put request to AWS S3.

My epics is as follow

```
...

function uploadFile(mimetype, url, file) {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': mimetype,
    },
    onUploadProgress(progress) {
      const percentCompleted = Math.round((progress.loaded * 100) / progress.total)
      uploadProgress(percentCompleted)
    },
  }

  axiosRetry(axios, { retries: 3 })

  return axios.put(url, file[0], config)
}

export const uploadEpic = (action$, store) => action$
  .ofType(SIGNED_URL_SUCCESS)
  .mergeMap(() => {
    const file = store.getState().File.droppedFile
    const mimetype = file[0].type
    const { url } = store.getState().SignedUrl
    const { fileData } = store.getState().Upload

    return of(uploadFile(mimetype, url.data, file))
      .concatMap(() => {
        const uploadedData = {
          url: fileData.url,
          thumbUrl: `${fileData.folder}/${fileData.filename}-00001.png`,
        }
        return [
          upload(uploadedData),
          uploadSuccess(),
        ]
      })
      .catch(error => of(uploadFailure(error)))
  })

export default uploadEpic
```

The upload seems to work, as i received an AWS SNS email telling that its done, but i can't seem to see that it is updating the Upload.progress state inside my Upload reducer.

The reason i am using axios is particulary because its `axios-retry` and its `onUploadProgress`, since i can't seem to find an example doing an onProgress using [universal-rx-request](https://github.com/datacamp/universal-rx-request)

so two questions probably

1. How can i achieve this using axios
2. How can i achieve this using universal-rx-request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41884813/387808)

I ended up not using axios at all

I got it working with this

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of'
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/observable/dom/ajax'

import { SIGNED_URL_SUCCESS } from 'ducks/SignedUrl'

import {
  upload,
  uploadIsLoading,
  uploadSuccess,
  uploadFailure,
  uploadProgress,
} from 'ducks/Upload'

export const uploadEpic = (action$, store) => action$
  .ofType(SIGNED_URL_SUCCESS)
  .mergeMap(() => {
    const file = store.getState().File.droppedFile
    const mimetype = file[0].type
    const { url } = store.getState().SignedUrl
    const { fileData } = store.getState().Upload

    const progressSubscriber = new Subject()
    const request = Observable.ajax({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: url.data,
      body: file[0],
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': mimetype,
      },
      progressSubscriber,
    })

    const requestObservable = request
      .concatMap(() => {
        const uploadedData = {
            ...
        }
        return [
          upload(uploadedData),
          uploadIsLoading(false),
          uploadSuccess(),
        ]
      })
      .catch(error => of(uploadFailure(error)))

    return progressSubscriber
      .map(e => ({ percentage: (e.loaded / e.total) * 100 }))
      .map(data => uploadProgress(data.percentage))
      .merge(requestObservable)
  })
```

**UPDATE:** [on rxjs 6 the merge operators is deprecated](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/deprecations), so if you're using rxjs 6, change the code above to

```
// some/lib/folder/uploader.js
import { of, merge } from 'rxjs' // import merge here
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/ajax'
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators' // instead of here
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'


export function storageUploader(...args) {
  const progressSubscriber = new Subject()

  const request = ajax({...someRequestOptions})
    .pipe(
      map(() => success()),
      catchError((error) => of(failure(error))),
    )

  const subscriber = progressSubscriber
    .pipe(
      map((e) => ({ percentage: (e.loaded / e.total) * 100 })),
      map((upload) => progress(upload.percentage)),
      catchError((error) => of(failure(error))),
    )

  return merge(subscriber, request) // merge both like this, instead of chaining the request on progressSubscriber
}


//the_epic.js
export function uploadEpic(action$, state$) {
  return action$
    .pipe(
      ofType(UPLOAD),
      mergeMap((someUploadOptions) => uploaderLib(
        { ...someUploadOptions },
        actionSuccess,
        actionFailure,
        actionProgress,
      )),
      catchError((error) => of(actionFailure(error))),
    )
}
```